# subprocess.check_output(..) process returning the same output when run in loop

Tags: python, subprocess, cpu-usage

I am a novice in python. So please bear with me :)

I want to write a script which will check the CPU utilization of the system and in case it crosses a threshold, it should take thread dumps along with other details.
I have written a script in python as below and using "vmstat" command to see the user cycle and system cycle.
In case these 2 combined exceeds the threshold, I will take thread dumps.

```
while True:
    output = subprocess.check_output("vmstat|tail -1", shell=True).decode('utf-8');
    m = re.search(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+\d+$", output)
    print('US', int(m.group(1)))
    print('SY', int(m.group(2)))
    # us: Time spent running non-kernel code. (user time, including nice time)
    # sy: Time spent running kernel code. (system time)
    usage=int(m.group(1))+int(m.group(2))
    if usage>CPU:
        ...
    else
        print "cpu usage is below threshold"
```

But issue is I am getting the same values

```
US 1
SY 0
cpu usage is below threshold
US 1
SY 0
cpu usage is below threshold
US 1
SY 0
cpu usage is below threshold
US 1
SY 0
cpu usage is below threshold
```

Simultaneously if I run "vmstat" command in a different console, then I can see different values for 'US' and 'SY' parameters - 
[image]

I think the subprocess.check_output(..) is running the "vmstat" process only once.
Can we somehow enable it to run every time?

Comment: Are you sure your regex is correct?

Comment: yes I verified it on the online compiler and its giving the correct data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python is OK, except for a missing semicolon after the `else`.

To see what's going wrong, start by making sure that the system is going to be busy.  Launch a cpu-intensive command in some other terminal window, something like:

```
  yes | wc -c
```

If you don't have a spare terminal window, start it in the background like this:

```
  yes | wc -c &
```

While that command is running, execute `vmstat 1 5` and see that it shows that the system is using CPU.

Now run the command that your program tells Python to execute:

```
  vmstat|tail -1
```

Do that a few times.  That will tell you why your program always shows the same numbers.  It's because `vmstat` with no arguments always shows the same numbers.

Well, technically that's not quite true, it doesn't always show the same values.  Those values can slowly change over time.  What's really happening is this (copied from the `vmstat` man page):

> `vmstat`  reports information about processes, memory, paging, block IO, traps, disks and cpu activity.
>
> The first report produced gives averages since the last reboot.

If your system has been up for a while then it's going to take a lot of activity to change the averages that are shown on that first line.

To fix, change your Python program to run `vmstat 1 2|tail -1`.  (Run that yourself a couple of times to check that it shows what you want it to show.)  Obviously it will take a second to accumulate and emit the up-to-date data, but for the purposes of this program that's probably acceptable.  Depending on how sensitive you want your monitoring to be you might even want to tell `vmstat` to sample over a longer period.

Don't forget to kill the CPU-waster that's running in the background or in some other terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs. I made changes in the script and added "vmstat 1 2|tail -1" after that I was able to get the correct details.